# Creating a view with Ajax/Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I've started using rails just a few months ago and I'm currently working on a reddit-type app. I just need to doublecheck my work for a prompt regarding the comment views/create.js.erb file. This the 'framework' of code:

```
if the comment is valid
  add the comment to the list of comments
else
  render an error on the form
end
```

This is how I thought it would be expressed. Am I correct in using ".show" and ".prepend" ? Or am I just incorrect all together? Do I need to provide additional information? Thank you for your help

```
<% if @comment.created? %>
  $<'#comment-' +<%= @comment.id %>.show();
<% else %>
  $('#comment-' +<%= @comment.id %>).prepend("<div class='alert alert-danger'><%flash[:error] %></div>");
<% end %>
```

added by request in comments:

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comments = @post.comments

    @comment = current_user.comments.build( comment_params )
    @comment.post = @post
    @new_comment = Comment.new

    authorize @comment

    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Comment was saved"
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the comment. Please try again."
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Comment: Could you post create method in your comments controller and create.js.erb code?

Comment: done! please see above